# How do I call a function inside a if...else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to call a function inside an if else in a function. I want to make a function, who use if else to call 1 function in each.

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/omo9yv9q/)

The first js code to call the other functions:

```
 function randomClick(number){
    var gamerand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (gamerand == 1){
        loseClick();
    }else{
        winClick();
};
```

Lose function:

```
function loseClick(number){
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (150 - 75 + 75)) + 1;
    var rprand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    var xprand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 100 + 100)) + 1;
    xp = parseInt(xp) + xprand;
    cookies = parseInt(cookies) + rand;
    rp = parseInt(rp) + rprand;
    losses = parseInt(losses) + 1;
}
```

Win function:

```
function winClick(number){
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 100 + 100)) + 1;
    var rprand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    var xprand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (300 - 150 + 150)) + 1;
    xp = parseInt(xp) + xprand;
    cookies = parseInt(cookies) + rand;
    rp = parseInt(rp) + rprand;
    wins = parseInt(wins) + 1;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need one more `}` to end the definition of `randomClick` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a missing `}` for your function `randomClick`

```
function randomClick(number){
    var gamerand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    if (gamerand == 1){
        loseClick();
    }else{
        winClick();
    }
}//This was missing
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `}` of `else` inside `randomClick()`.

You can use `ternary` operator as follow:

```
function randomClick(number) {
    var gamerand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1)) + 1;

    gamerand == 1 ? loseClick() : winClick();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/omo9yv9q/5/

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing `}`. It should work without problems with this fix.

```
     function randomClick(number){
        var gamerand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
        if (gamerand == 1){
            loseClick();
        }else{
            winClick();
//    missing one bracket here
    };
```